# Llamar un dato no vinculado de otra tabla en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, inner

tengo una duda en lo siguiente:
Tengo una tabla Tabla1 y tengo Tabla2 ambas están vinculadas por un ID. La primera tabla guarda 3 tipos de registros en un campo Estatus_Auditado, cuando el campo Estatus_Auditadoes 1 se adjunta automaticamente el ID de la Tabla2 haciendo que estén vinculadas, pero cuando guarda 2 o 3 el campo ID queda NULL haciendo que al tratar de juntar la tabla2 sólo me muestre los que tienen Estatus_Auditado1 pero yo en query quiero mostrar 1,2 y 3, entonces mi duda es cómo puedo llamar mi Tabla2 y que me muestre todos los Estatus en Tabla1

Aquí mi Tabla1
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí mi Tabla2 marqué el Id de donde se juntan ambas tablas y yo quiero en mi Tabla1 mandar a llamar el dato LPN de la Tabla2, cuando lo hago en mi query sólo me arroja el dato que tiene Estatus_Auditado 1 y yo quiero que aparezcan 1 y 3
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Me podrían ayudar?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Si no tenes id, como esperas unir ese campo a la otra tabla???

Comment: Cómo sabes cuales filas están relacionadas?

Comment: Por el dato de Id_Rel_Del_Item esa es mi llave primaría en la segunda Tabla.